# How to initialize a pointer to the length of an output buffer?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, pcre

I am using this code for regex replace using the [pcre2](http://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/) library:

```
PCRE2_SIZE outlengthptr=256;                       //this line
PCRE2_UCHAR* output_buffer;                        //this line
output_buffer=(PCRE2_UCHAR*)malloc(outlengthptr);  //this line
uint32_t rplopts=PCRE2_SUBSTITUTE_GLOBAL;
int ret=pcre2_substitute(
  re1234,                    /*Points to the compiled pattern*/
  subject,               /*Points to the subject string*/
  subject_length,        /*Length of the subject string*/
  0,                     /*Offset in the subject at which to start matching*/
  rplopts,               /*Option bits*/
  0,                     /*Points to a match data block, or is NULL*/
  0,                     /*Points to a match context, or is NULL*/
  replace,               /*Points to the replacement string*/
  replace_length,        /*Length of the replacement string*/
  output_buffer,         /*Points to the output buffer*/
  &outlengthptr          /*Points to the length of the output buffer*/
);
```

But I seem to not get how to define the `output_buffer` and a pointer to it's length (`outlengthptr`) properly.

The code works when I give a fixed value to the `outlengthptr` but it remains fixed i.e it doesn't get changed to new length of `output_buffer`. But according to [`pcre2_substitue()` specification](http://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2_substitute.html) it is supposed to be changed to the new lnegth of the `output_buffer`:

> The length, startoffset and rlength values are code units, not characters, as is the contents of the variable pointed at by `outlengthptr`, which is updated to the actual length of the new string.

The problem is:

1. When I make the `outlengthptr` a fixed value, the final string gets truncated at the fixed length.
2. And if I don't initialize the variable `outlengthptr`, I get a segmentation fault.

This is the prototype of the function:

```
 int pcre2_substitute(const pcre2_code *code, PCRE2_SPTR subject, PCRE2_SIZE length, PCRE2_SIZE startoffset, uint32_t options, pcre2_match_data *match_data, pcre2_match_context *mcontext, PCRE2_SPTR replacement, PCRE2_SIZE rlength, PCRE2_UCHAR *outputbuffer, PCRE2_SIZE *outlengthptr);
```

[This is the man page of the function](http://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2_substitute.html).

Comment: OK, try mallocating 64k, call, realloc afterwards if you need to.

Comment: If the result is getting truncated, make the fixed value bigger? Much bigger? (If necessary keep doubling its size until you don't get truncation.)

Comment: `malloc(outlengthptr)` should be `malloc(outlengthptr * sizeof *output_buffer)`

Comment: To get the best possible answers, post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: "When I make the outlengthptr a fixed value, the final string gets truncated at the fixed length."  - I would say that that is how it is supposed to work. If you don't want output to be truncated then pass a buffer that is big enough to fit the whole output.

Comment: @M.M yeah, but the length and size of the output buffer is supposed to be managed by the substitute function.

Comment: Some APIs allow you to pass `NULL` for `outputbuffer` and then they will write the optimal output length ... this documentation doesn't indicate that this API supports that but perhaps you could try it

Comment: @Jahid no it isn't. The caller is responsible for managing the output buffer.

Comment: You could possibly calculate the required buffer size by running a match with callout function first , and in the callout function keep a running total of how much space would be needed to do the substitution

Comment: A pointer is not an array! And pick **one** language! C is not C++ is not C.

Comment: @Olaf let's no try to be rude here, The libary I am using is written in pure C, And I am using that code in my c++ project. It involves both of them... And please explain what your comment `A pointer is not an array` has to do anything here...

Comment: @Jahid: No one is being rude. I just clarified what is true. You asked: "How to initialize a pointer to the length of an output buffer?". Well, you cannot. A pointer does not hav a length property like an array (i.e. the length of the **referenced** object). And here might very well be different answers possible, depending on the language you use.

Comment: Note that `outlengthptr` is the name of the pointer. So your variable would be `outlength`, not a pointer.

Comment: @Olaf You should've checked my code first. `outlengthptr` is a variable which contains the length of the buffer. and I am passing the address to the function. And I don't have any idea where you got the `outlength` variable. And also two lang tags mean any answer in either of them is acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [pcre2api page](http://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2api.html#SEC34) says the following (emphasis mine):

> The function returns the number of replacements that were made. This may be zero if no matches were found, and is never greater than 1 unless `PCRE2_SUBSTITUTE_GLOBAL` is set. In the event of an error, a negative error code is returned. Except for `PCRE2_ERROR_NOMATCH` (which is never returned), any errors from `pcre2_match()` or the substring copying functions are passed straight back. `PCRE2_ERROR_BADREPLACEMENT` is returned for an invalid replacement string (unrecognized sequence following a dollar sign), **and `PCRE2_ERROR_NOMEMORY` is returned if the output buffer is not big enough.**

So start with an initial buffer which should accomodate most of the results - not too big and not too small. This depends on your application.
You could for instance try to start with 120% of the length of the input string as a heuristic, as this seems a reasonable bet for most common regex replacement usages.

Then, call the function with this buffer, and pass it its size.

- If you get a positive result (or zero), you're done.
- If you get `PCRE2_ERROR_NOMEMORY`, you double the buffer size and try again (repeat this step as many times as needed)
- If you get a different error code, handle it accordingy as a genuine error case.

Comment: This is a good workaround, but it involves multiple call of the same function. That will take some extra time...

Comment: @Jahid I've added a paragraph. If you choose the start size wisely, you can get away with 1 or 2 iterations for most cases. As always: *measure*. If you're doing too many iterations, change your assumptions. If you do it well, this won't be a problem in practice.

Comment: Alternatively, you could send a feature request for a function which would calculate the required buffer size - but the drawback of such an approach would be that the *minimal* number of regex matches that would have to be performed would always be 2 (once for the size estimation, and once for the real replacement). I'd say the performance penalty would be greater, as regex matching takes more time than string copying. The **ideal** feature would be to ask for this function to update `outlengthptr` to the required size when it returns `PCRE2_ERROR_NOMEMORY`, but that would be a breaking change

Comment: I think I will file a bug report, the function is supposed to update the `outlengthptr` as the buffer size according to it's specification.

Comment: And for the time being I will go with FILENAME_MAX as I am working with files.